# How to execute 7zip commands from nant script?

Tags: zip, release, nant, 7zip

I need to execute 7zip commands from nant script. How can I do that?

I have tried it like this, but it is not working

> &ltexec program="7z.exe" basedir="${sevenzipinstalldir}" commandline="7z a D:\NantTest\Experiment\NewLab\7ziptest.zip -pmypassword D:\NantTest\Experiment\NewLab\"

Comment: (1) What did you expect it to do? (2) What did it _actually_ do? **Every single bug report or problem should contain that information.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<exec program="7z.exe" basedir="${sevenzipinstalldir}" commandline="a D:\NantTest\Experiment\NewLab\7ziptest.zip -pmypassword D:\NantTest\Experiment\NewLab\" />
```

(Don't repeat the executable name in `commandline`.)